# Is there an efficient way to filter and apply a function to this dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with columns origin, destination, and cost. There are x origins and y destinations. Each origin is mapped to the y destinations with corresponding cost.

My goal is to create a new column that shows the number of destinations that can be reached from each origin, given the amount of budget spent. I can easily do this for each origin alone but that takes forever to go through x different origins.

Is there a way to filter this huge dataset define a function to arrive at the correct result of destinations for each origin?

Comment: If you can provide some sample data , I think one of us can help you out

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you need.  For instance, is the goal to find how many different cities you can reach from New York on a total budget of $10,000 ?  Or which cities are reachable in one hop from NYC for no more than $2,000?

Comment: Are you allowed two-hop flights?  Can any destinations also serve as origins?

Comment: Looking the problem from a 2 dimensional dataset is a bad idea, the best way is to use a graph data structure with origin and destination as nodes and budget as weight of edges

Comment: with your edited question, I think it should be as easy as `x.groupby('OriginID').apply(lambda x: np.sum(x.Budget<15))`

Comment: @Prune: In the data you will find specific budget number for each origin-destination pair. The goal is to find how many destinations are reachable for each amount of budget for each origin. Don't worry about hopping flights or anything. There is no overlap between origins and destinations

jeremycg: that's the idea. We find how many destination we can reach for a particular amount of budget. As the budget increases, the number of possible destination goes up. 

pratiklodha: could you take a look at the data and suggest how it can be done?

Comment: @jeremycg: the problem is that the budget number is not fixed. There are as many budget numbers as the number of row in the dataset, and we are looking for the answers for each row

Comment: @Prune, if your question is: "how many origin-destination pairs cost less than X" and you want to ask this question many times, then the fastest way is to sort the budget column ascending in an array and then do a binary search for X, the position in the array is the number of pairs with budget <= X.

Comment: @Alice_inwonderland: should that second sentence list your third column as "cost", rather than "budget"?

Comment: I suspect that the solution will be simply to sort the data set by origin, then by destination cost.  For each origin, add destination costs from lowest to highest, until you run out or hit the budget limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I read the question carefully and this should give you what you need.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')    

def get_cumulative_destinations(row): 
    return len(df.loc[(df['OriginID'] == row['OriginID']) & (df['Budget'] <= row['Budget'])].Destination)

df['Cumulative destination'] = df.apply(get_cumulative_destinations, axis=1)
```

Answer:

```
OriginID    Destination Label   Budget  Cumulative destination
2507    661 Hos 9.78    30
2507    502 CC  9.98    31
2507    566 Rec 14.76   55
2507    483 CC  20.54   90
2507    461 CC  8.58    20
2507    452 CC  12.22   38
2507    440 CC  14.82   56
2507    516 Rec 14.27   52
2507    580 Rec 15.27   62
...
```

Comment: Wow it works perfectly. This is exactly what I need. Doing all that in just a short line of code. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. Please accept the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of the question is you want the number of locations reachable per origin, using the given budget for the trip. So, kind of like the number of other destinations you can reach using the same price.

We can do this by grouping the data by origin, then ranking the budgets - using the `method = 'max'` we take the maximum ranking during ties:

```
x.groupby('OriginID').apply(lambda x: x.Budget.rank(method = 'max'))
```